# Could a 32 inch TV be used as a high-resolution PC monitor to display more content than my current monitor?

Tags: display

I currently have a 19 inch monitor.  Would the large screen of a 32 inch TV give me more pixels to display more content, or would the resolution be comparable and the image just bigger?

The 32 inch TV has almost three times the screen area.  I would like to display multiple screen images of what is the current resolution, tiled onto the much larger screen, or display the equivalent content of several current screens.  Does it work this way, or does the current screen content get automatically bigger in proportion, so the same number of windows will fill my screen but just a lot bigger?

Comment: you should reword your question to make it less opinion based.

Comment: I'm nominating this for reopening because of the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Your TV will be, at best, 1920x1080 resolution unless you're lucky enough to have a new 4k TV.

If your existing monitor is the same resolution [a fair assumption these days for a 19" screen, but you gave no details], then everything will simply be correspondingly bigger.

You don't get any 'more space' you just get everything bigger & consequently blurrier - especially as TVs are rarely as sharp as computer monitors.

It might be fun for playing games on, from 6ft away, but unlikely to be great fun for writing your next thesis.

Comment: At 19″, it’s either 1280x1024, 1440x900 or 1366x768. Nobody buys these anymore, anyway. ;)

Comment: then it might be a close call as to which is 'best' ;)

Comment: mine is 1440 x 900 after buying a different pc, before it was 1280 x 1024. My monitor says 1440 is the highest setting in the resolution bar.